# CodeIgniter - PHP Set_Radio on Radio Input

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, validation

I am working on a website, and I have run into a problem. In order to pre-set or re-input slected values, Codeigniter allows you to use set_radio to solve your problem, seen here:

```
<td>Do You Have a PayPal Account <span class="error">*</span> : </td>
<td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><label>   
  <!-- used for validation -->
    <input type="hidden" id="temp_mid" value="" />
    <input name="mail_account" type="radio" id="p_same" value="same" onclick="dohide_show(this.value);" <?php echo set_radio('mail_account', 'same'); ?>/> Yes(same as email address as above.)<br/>
    <input name="mail_account" type="radio" id="p_diff" value="diff" onclick="dohide_show(this.value);" <?php echo set_radio('mail_account', 'diff'); ?>/> Yes(different than above.)<br/>
    <input name="mail_account" type="radio" id="p_checkInMail" value="checkInMail" onclick="dohide_show(this.value);" <?php echo set_radio('mail_account', 'checkInMail'); ?>/> No(I would prefer to receive a check in the mail.)                  
     <?php echo form_error('mail_account'); ?>           

 </td>
```

This works perfectly fine after validation, as the previous radio button has been selected if there is an error in another part of the form. BUT, when trying to resubmit the page after the user has corrected the error, valditation fails on the radio selection, asking me to click on the radio buttons again, even if the radio button is visually selected on the option I chose before. So I have to choose the radio button again before I can resubmit the form. The alert called is seen here:

```
function validate_playpal()
        {   
            var temp=$('#temp_mid').val();
            if(temp=="")
            {
                alert('Please select the PayPal account option.');                  
                $('#p_same').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('p_diff').checked== true && document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').value=='')
            {
                alert('Please provide your PayPal email address.');
                document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if(document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').value!='')
            {
                if(!email_format(document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').value)){
                    alert('Please enter valid email address.');
                    document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').value="";
                    document.getElementById('paypal_emailid').focus();
                    return false;               
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working, even though it is repopulating the form correctly? Thanks.

EDIT:

For everyone who asked for what Mid_temp does, it appears to me that it just hides the buttons if they do not need to be selected. In the code I have, these are the only places it is mentioned:

```
    $('#bx').hide();
if(document.getElementById('p_diff').checked==true){    
    $('#bx').show();
}

function dohide_show(val){
    if(val=='diff')
    {       
        $('#bx').show();
        $('#paypal_emailid').val('');
        document.getElementById('p_diff').checked=true;
        $('#temp_mid').val('clicked');
    }
    else if(val=='same')
    {       
        $('#bx').hide();
        $('#paypal_emailid').val($('#email_id').val());
        $('#temp_mid').val('clicked');  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#bx').hide();
        $('#paypal_emailid').val($('#email_id').val());
        $('#temp_mid').val('clicked');
    }

}
```

and here, in a completely separate file:

```
function hide_box()
            {
                $('#bx').hide();
                $('#paypal_emailid').val('');
                $('#temp_mid').val('clicked');
            }
            function show_box()
            {
                $('#bx').show();
                $('#paypal_emailid').focus();
                $('#temp_mid').val('clicked');
            }
```

Also, Paypal Email ID is just checking the paypal email address that the user put in if they have a paypal account. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: please provide the `dohide_show(this.value);` function

Comment: What alert is called? What is `paypal_emailid` element? What function is populate the `temp_mid` element? Provide more information about your problem and I will try to help you

Comment: I will try to get you more information on this tomorrow, as I don't have access to it now. Sorry

Comment: The email ID just sees if the user has a paypal email, then validates it, if he/she doesn't have one, then it doesn't worry about it. The alert called is,"Please Select the Paypal Account Option". Temp_mid just sees whether to show this set of question at all. I have put the new code on the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you doesn't repopulate the `id="temp_mid"` field but check it here `if(temp=="")`
. Maybe you need to repopulate it too?

Comment: try to replace the `<input type="hidden" id="temp_mid" value="" />` with `<input type="hidden" id="temp_mid" value="<?php echo ($this->input->post('mail_account')) ? 'clicked' : ''?>" />`

Comment: It means repopulate the `temp_mid` field with `clicked` value if `mail_account` field is passed in the POST

Answer (score 0):

What error message are you getting, "Please select the PayPal account option."?

**This will always fail**

```
<input type="hidden" id="temp_mid" value="" />

......
var temp=$('#temp_mid').val();
if(temp=="")
{
    alert('Please select the PayPal account option.');                  
    $('#p_same').focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well, it doesn't always fail....Only when something else fails. But wait, why does that always fail? Well, I always get Please select the Paypal option after something else that fails validation is fixed.

Comment: Please update your code above with any changes you made. What does temp_mid do?

Comment: just hides the radio boxes or not. Added that code to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mikhail suggested you are not repopulating the value for the `temp_mid` hidden field. In order to avoid having to repopulate it you could just dispose that field and detect if an option for the radio button has been selected using **jQuery** in the following way:

```
function validate_playpal()
{   
    if($('[name="mail_account"]:checked').size() > 0)
    {
        alert('Please select the PayPal account option.');                  
        $('#p_same').focus();
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Notice the `if` statement in the third line `$('[name="mail_account"]:checked').size() > 0`.

Hope it helps-